# Change the frame of custom collection cell's subview in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I made a custom collection view cell for collection view.

I want to subview's set the frame according to screen size.

But my `InwithFrame` or `initwithcoder` method is not getting called & collection view is just load nib from the `xib file.`

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: hace you try `awakeFromNib`?

Comment: @Virussmca, thanks a lot man!!! Its Working!!! Plz post as an Answer so that I can Accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with **awakeFromNib**.
awakeFromNib is called when the nib file associated with a class is loaded from disk. Any class that can own a nib can use it.

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NSLog(@"awake from nib");
}
```